# Inspecting google hangout chat box using document.getElementById("id") not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Today I was trying to learn how the google hangout chatbox was designed, so I started by using google chrome inspector tool. I right clicked on the chatbox text input element and inspect it. This is what I get.

```
<div id=":cb.f" class="vE dQ editable" aria-label="Text entry field for Hangout with jhon carib" g_editable="true" role="textbox" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

so looking at the html it seems like the id of the element is **:cb.f** but when I right click and copy the css path I found this: 
"*#\3a cb\2e f*"
which means the id is **\3a**.

and none of *document.getElementById("\3a")* or **document.getElementById(":cb.f")** gets the element node, even using the class names does not work.

can someone explain what is happening here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using hangout extension in Chrome. Chrome opens up google extension chat window in iframe. So you have to get hold of iframe and then select the dom element inside the iframe.

Comment: I accepted because you answered why it does not work, but getting hold of the iframe will not enable me to inspect the dom for sake of Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the hangout chat windows are in an own iframe and you need to get hold of the chat iframe's document. This isn't possible when using the gmail website because they don't share the same origin.

**But**: google released a dedicated website for hangouts on https://hangouts.google.com which does share the same origin.

You can now access the chat div like so:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('iframeid'); // id changes on every reload
var doc = frm.contentDocument;
var chat = doc.getElementById(':cb.f'); // this id also changes on every reload
```